# Can't use inheritance in a std::visit functor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, variant, visitor-pattern

I have the following code:

```
class multitype {
public:
 int get_number() const;
 .....
private:
std::variant<int, std::string, ..... > field;
};

.....

struct zero_return {
    template<typename X> int operator()(const X&) const { return 0; }
};

inline int multitype::get_number() const
{
    struct visitor : public zero_return {
        int operator()(int n) const { return n; }
    };
    return std::visit(visitor(), field);
}
```

While the actual code has many more types in the `std::variant` and is much more complex, the above code fragment is sufficient to reproduce the issue by itself.

The idea behind the `zero_return` struct in this example was supposed to provide a particular default return value for any type not specifically handled by a subclass functor.

However, the line with the call to std::visit fails with the following message:

```
error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(multitype::get_number() const::visitor, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'
  972 |    return std::__invoke(std::forward<_Visitor>(__visitor),
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  973 |        __element_by_index_or_cookie<__indices>(
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  974 |   std::forward<_Variants>(__vars))...);
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A TL;DR of the dupe: you need a `using zero_return::operator();`

Comment: The dupe uses multiple inheritance, though

Comment: @markt1964: That's irrelevant; you have to do the `using` trick regardless of how many base classes you use.

Comment: I thought you would only need using to disambiguate if multiple base classes had a match